# Как можно сделать "трансформацию" из одного текста в другой

Tags: python

Необходимо сделать что бы из текста, допустим `'Hello World'` (Вместо этих, может быть любые слова, которые ввел пользователь) переводились в `'Ｈｅｌｌｏ　ｗｏｒｌｄ'`

Готовый "алфавит" из подобных символов: `ＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ`
Нижний регистр: `ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚ`

Подскажите как можно такое реализовать.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```py
trans = str.maketrans('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
                      'ＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ'
                      'ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚ')

print('Hello World'.translate(trans))
```